# How do I quote multiple paragraphs?

Tags: quotes, citation

I'm writing a rhetorical analysis paper on Grendel and I'm quoting the following:

> *The monster laughs.*
>
> Time-space cross-section: *Wealtheow*.
>
> Cut *A:*

Do I block quote? I think the paragraph breaks in the passage are significant and will be part of my analysis so I want to make sure that visually it will be seen, but I'm not quite sure if that would be the correct way to quote it.

Comment: It is not clear what you are quoting--selections from the poem or ballad, summaries of action, what?

Comment: You seem to have successfully quoted multiple paragraphs in writing this post... so what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should always use a block quote when quoting multiple lines of text (as you have done in this question).